# A script in Linux to view total size of removed files

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to write a script in Linux which pauses the session for the number of seconds given as argument, and then displays the total size of all files whose names were removed from the current directory. The output in the end should look like...

```
$ watchdir 60
# sleeping for a while ...
removed files total size: (size of removed files) eg.2345
```

I can only display the size of the current directory using du command and not the size of the removed file.

Comment: `using du command and not the size of the removed file.` So get the size of directory. Wait 60 seconds. Then get the size of directory again. Compute difference and display it....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of watchdir.sh to produce the report with time-stamps and pertinent stats:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "Dir and Sleep_seconds?" && exit
DIR=$1
SLEEPTIME=$2

# Note: The assumption is that DIR size is always decreasing as files are being deleted
PREV_SIZE=`du -s $DIR | awk '{print $1}'`
while true
do
  CURR_SIZE=`du -s $DIR | awk '{print $1}'`
  DIFF_SIZE=$(( $PREV_SIZE - $CURR_SIZE ))
  echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %T'` CURR_SIZE=$CURR_SIZE REMOVED=$DIFF_SIZE"
  PREV_SIZE=$CURR_SIZE
  sleep $SLEEPTIME
done
```

and running it like this:

```
watchdir.sh /home/mike/testdir 10
```

produced this as files in /home/mike/testdir are being deleted:

```
2020-07-04 00:29:43 CURR_SIZE=736 REMOVED=0
2020-07-04 00:29:53 CURR_SIZE=696 REMOVED=40
2020-07-04 00:30:03 CURR_SIZE=668 REMOVED=28
2020-07-04 00:30:13 CURR_SIZE=652 REMOVED=16
2020-07-04 00:30:23 CURR_SIZE=640 REMOVED=12
2020-07-04 00:30:33 CURR_SIZE=640 REMOVED=0
```